# How can I use images to change the colour of objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

can I make an object coloriser like this? Is about car coloriser.

1. List of 23 thumbs images which means a colour or a mix of colours.
2. When you click the colour to show the image with car in the right colour.

Comment: I have no idea if you are able to do that, but yes, it can be done.

Comment: :)) you're funny... so it can be done but I am not able to do it. why?

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an image of each car with each color.

For each thumb image, give it an id corresponding to its color, and one class for a listener.

Create a click listener for the class, and display the correct image based on the clicked thumb image id.

If you want a better answer you're going to have to provide some code.

Comment: So I have created span classes for each colour and I have images for each car. <span class="color1" style="width: 70px; height: 70px; top: 500px; left: 80px;"></span>